# What era and region’s secular style is the Hasidic form of dress based on?

Tags: clothing, fashion, judaism

Is there some land and time in history in which an entire society’s men and women dressed in what is today the Hasidic style of dress?

If so, then when and where was this? And were there still differences between the normal style back then and the way that Hasidim do now?

I’m wondering in particular, for example, whether the non Jewish women in that society would have been so inflexibly fixed in their wearing of long sleeves and leggings etc even in the hot summers as Hasidic women are expected to as a matter of religious mandate.

Comment: I don't think women's dress is particularly striking: religious Muslim women wear long dresses snd sleeves, also cover their head (and even their face.) And Europeans used to do the same until not so ling ago.

Comment: I’m not saying it was exceptionally striking compared to Muslim women or otherwise. I think you’re easing into the question a level of cynicism that is not there.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: @Frank I am not sure what you mean by *cynicism* - I just gave you two examples of societies where women dressed in the same way. I am not not sure of anything as particular to hasidic women dress comparable, e.g., to men's shtreimels - which is probably what you are referring to in the first part of the question.

Comment: @MCW I think tzitzit is not particularly hasidic, but has broader religious meaning for Jews.

Comment: Imagine asking this question about "the Japanese form of dress" or even "the American form of dress"... This question is almost as vague. You could ask about specific items but in many cases it's hard to answer. For example from Wikipedia, "The origins of the spodik and the shtreimel are unclear, but it is often thought that the Jews living in Europe adopted wearing fur hats from the Eastern European culture, and perhaps from the nobility, replacing the sudra."

Comment: @BrianZ You really don't think that "Hasidic form of dress" is just a tiny bit more specific than "American form of dress"?

Comment: @cmw it depends on what one defines as Hasidic - the question likely refers to the modern religious current, marked by their peculiar and old-fashioned customs and dress - aka "Jewish Amish". Their clothing is more of a modern fashion statement - rejection of modern cultural, religious, and political developments, rather than a rigorous reference to their historical origin. Not sure how hassidim overlap with [Naturei Karta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neturei_Karta), who reject the state of Israel as premature - supposedly a Jewish state cannot be re-created before the coming of messiah.

Comment: The claims about the origins of Shtreimel seem to be very controversial - ranging from its similarity to Russian or Tatar winter hats, to the claim that Spanish Jews were forced to wear fur of impure animals, as a sign of humiliation (not sure, if there are Spanish/Sephardic hassids.)

Comment: @RogerVadim and all that would make for a good answer.

Comment: What are the cultural influences that shaped Hasidic dress?